# Object-oriented programming in VB.NET and C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, oop

can any one suggest some good tutorials where i can read about the actual object oriented concepts which we use in real time scenarios. Not the "class is a container. fruit is a parent class and apple is a child class" kind of stuff.

Recently i was developing a multithreaded GUI application in vb.net and found out many obstacles like using one form's element in another form, changing form property in other class, when to create objects to access elements and many other stuff stumped me.

Can some one pleas suggest some links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing aren't OO concepts, they're concurrency concepts. You can learn some about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_pattern. You can read about some specific design patterns related to concurrent programming here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_pattern

[This looks like a good read](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) for C# specific stuff.

Comment: @jax perhaps you should re-read both his question and my response. my response HAS a link specific to C#. The problems that he's running into (if you spent the time to read the entire question) is centered around multithreading. I think you may be a little to quick on the trigger there with the downvote as well as with your reading/thinking about questions before answering.

Answer (score 1):

Quote a:

> Not the "class is a container. fruit is a parent class and apple is a child class" kind of stuff.

Quote b:

> obstacles like using one form's element in another form, chaning form property in other class

You should really study the Apple/Fruit stuff so your design does not call for Forms accessing each others elements.

Comment: ive read and understood those concepts. But when developing real time stuff i had the need to call the form elements and modify them from another class.

Comment: @swordf: maybe describe some concrete problems? Right now I can't tell if they're organizational or threading issues.

Comment: @swordfish - It's been a number of years since I've used C#, but rather than accessing form elements directly, couldn't you have a central class somewhere that all forms that need to display/edit the data have references to?

Comment: my application is a bit tricky. For instance it has a thread which needs to add elemets to a listview and based on the added elements in the third column of the list view the colour of the row must change. Now this entire thread is another class. Already cross threaded calls to form elements must be through a delegate and cross class call through an instance of the class. This is just one of the many obstacles i have and am absolutly stumped.

Comment: @swordfish: unfortunately, it sounds to me like the architecture needs to be refactored. look into the links that i gave in my post for a clearer understanding of multithreading.

Answer (score 1):

[Object Oriented Software Construction by Bertrand Meyer.](http://docs.eiffel.com/book/method/object-oriented-software-construction-2nd-edition)

Answer (score 0):

I will you suggest classical tutorial for [Object-Oriented Analysis and Design with Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020189551X) from Grady Booch, its a really great book